# Pointers and Object slicing

Tags: c++, pointers, object-slicing

I'm learning the hard way about object slicing, and I'm wondering if it is possible for a pointer to ever be object sliced.  In other words:

- Can pointers ever be victims of object slicing or are you always safe from object slicing as long as you're using a pointer?

Comment: You'll probably learn best from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: I like how you ask contradictory questions `Can pointers ever be victims of object slicing?` and `are you always safe from object slicing as long as you're using a pointer?`. This makes answers confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -- a pointer to `base` is required to be able to refer to an object of any type derived from `base` and still retain the correct type for the derived object (and for what it's worth, the same is true with references).

Comment: "Yes it is always safe."  His question admits not a "yes" or "no" answer.

Answer (score 15):

It depends on how loosely you're willing to define "slicing". In a sense, when you point to a derived object with a base pointer (or reference), any non-virtual functions get sliced. For instance:

```
class A {
    void Print() { cout << "Class A\n"; }
};

class B : public A {
    void DoB() {}
    void Print() { cout << "Class B\n"; }
};

B b;
A* a = &b;
a->DoB(); // Won't compile!
a->Print(); // Prints "Class A", not "Class B"
```

The call to `DoB` doesn't work because we're using a pointer to an `A`, so the compiler doesn't know it can call `DoB` on that pointer. In this way, you're losing part of `B`, so you can think of this as a form of slicing.

The last line in particular is an example of a phenomenon called "name hiding". Because `Print` wasn't declared `virtual` in the base class, and our pointer is of type `A`, the compiler doesn't know that it should call `B::Print` instead of `A::Print`.

An important example of this problem comes into play with your destructor:

```
class A {
    ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
    std::vector<int> v;
};

A* a = new B;
delete a; // What happens to B::v? Undefined behaviour!
```

Here, because the destructor wasn't marked as `virtual`, it called the base class's destructor in a non-virtual context, which means `B`'s destructor won't get called.